# searching a text file for an inputted word in python

Tags: python, list, text, for-loop, while-loop

So basically i have a big list of words in a text file that i want to be able to search through for matching words when the user inputs one to check the spelling, this is what i have so far.

```
f = open('words.txt', 'r')
wordCheck = input("please enter the word you would like to check the spelling of: ")

for line in f:
    if 'wordCheck' == line:
        print ('That is the correct spelling for '+wordCheck)
    else:
        print ( wordCheck+ " is not in our dictionary")
    break
```

When i enter a word i just get the else statement straight away, i dont think it even read through the text file.
Should i use a while loop instead?

```
while wordCheck != line in f
```

I am new to python and eventually i want the user to be able to input a word and if the spelling is incorrect, the program should print out a list of matching words(75% of the letters or more matching).

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Why do you have `break` in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
wordCheck = raw_input("please enter the word you would like to check the spelling of: ")
with open("words.txt", "r") as f:
    found = False    
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == wordCheck:
            print ('That is the correct spelling for '+ wordCheck)
            found = True
            break
    if not found:
        print ( wordCheck+ " is not in our dictionary")
```

This takes an input, opens the file then checks line by line if the input word matches the line in the dictionary if it is it prints the message, other wise if it has no lines left prints input word is not in dictionary.

Comment: The `while line` and the `.readline()`'s seem a bit convoluted... Why not just `for line in f`?

Comment: Also, makes more sense to remove the `\n` from the line, not add it to the string... `if line.strip() == wordCheck` and the `str(wordCheck)` is redundant as `raw_input` is always a string

Comment: And lastly, if it's not found, then `found` won't exist (set it to `False` before looping), so you'll get a `NameError` on that line... and, Once it's found, you should `break` so you stop going through the file

Answer (score 0):

Because you've only looped through the first line before it breaks.

```
wordCheck = input("please enter the word you would like to check the spelling of: ")
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if wordCheck in line.split():
            print('That is the correct spelling for '+wordCheck)
            break
    else:
        print(wordCheck + " is not in our dictionary")
```

The `for/else` here is used so if the word is not found in any line, the `else:` block would run.

Comment: that solves the not searching bit, but now its printing the else statement for every line of the file (10000+ words) i just want it to run and when it finds something to print out the result

Comment: @JohnConneely It shouldn't print the `else` for every line, but only after the loop if `break` has not been called

Comment: Your copy/paste of example code still has the same error. `'wordcheck' == line:` is not using the `wordCheck` variable assigned in the input command

Comment: Oops, that should have been `in` and not `==`

Comment: ya that works! thanks, i think i will use @muski's answer too to move forward!

Comment: Still not correct. Typo `'andr'` will match with `'andrew'` now because of the `in` instead of `==`. Probably also worth stripping the (probable) trailing new line characters picked up due to reading from the file. I'd guess it's one word per line.

Comment: I put `.split()` in, which splits the line into words

Answer (score 0):

It won't do spelling as per a proper spelling algorithm, but you can find *similar* words:

```
from difflib import get_close_matches

with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as fin:
    words = set(line.strip().lower() for line in fin)

testword = 'hlelo'
matches = get_close_matches(testword, words, n=5)
if testword == matches[0]:
    print 'okay'
else:
    print 'Not sure about:', testword
    print 'options:', ', '.join(matches)

#Not sure about: hlelo
#options: helot, hello, leo, hollow, hillel
```

You can adjust the "cutoff" and other parameters - check the docs for [get_close_matches](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches) in the [difflib module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html)

What you probably want to do is have a look at: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aspell-python/1.13 which is a Python wrapper around the `aspell` library, which'll do better suggestions and will extend to multiple dictionaries as well.